# Display post link if article object is not null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I display a link to the article path if the article object is not null?

so something like:

```
<% if @article is not null %>
<a href="<%%= article_path @article >">link</a>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use your controller or model to ensure that this is never the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This reads nicer in my opinion:

```
<% if @article %>
  <%= link_to 'link', @article %>
<% end %>
```

"If there is an article, link to it using the following display text and object."

A friend also points out that this could be shortened to this:

```
<%= link_to("link", @article) if @article %>
```

But personally, I prefer the first one.

Answer (score 5):

```
<%= link_to 'link', @article unless @article.nil? %>
```